# How to reverse Array in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

So i am working on a code to reverse Array in OCaml but I don't know why it is not working. It throws me syntax error;

> > array.(i) <- array(len-i-1) Error: Syntax error

Here is code:

```
let reverse array = let len=Array.length array in
        for i=0 to (len/2) do 
            let temp = array.(i)
            array.(i) <- array(len-i-1)
            array(len-i-1) <- temp          
        done;
        array;;
```

EDIT: Working version:

```
let reverse array = let len=Array.length array in
        for i=0 to (len/2) do 
            let temp = array.(i) in
            array.(i) <- array.(len-i-1);
            array.(len-i-1) <- temp         
        done;
        array;;
```

Comment: Since you modify the array, I strongly suggest you don't return it. As is, the reader of a code using that function may think that the original array is left unchanged.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to replace the line "for i=0 to (len/2) do" with "for i = 0 to (len/2 -1) do"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `.` between `array` and `(`.

Other syntax problems:

- You need `in` after `let` (except at outermost level of a module).
- You need semicolon `;` between the two assignments.

Comment: You have many small errors, sorry. The next one I see is that you're missing `in` after `let`. And you need a semicolon  between the two assignment expressions.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an assignment. So you want to learn about OCaml and not just have somebody code up your homework for you. If you read up on the `let ... in` expression it should be pretty obvious what needs fixing.

Comment: Well I did that alone and I know what let and in mean and how it works, but I really don't see what is wrong here. I also searched the web, but code stil seems ok to me.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield already mentioned it: `let` must always be followed by `in`, except on the outermost level. You are missing a semicolon between the assignments. Lines 3 and 4

Comment: I haven't realized I used two let statements, I was looking only at first one. Now It works thank you!